# ColdFusion 9, session ID predictability

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I inherited a website that uses ColdFusion 9.0.2. A scanner reports a predictable cookie session ID. The fix for this is supposedly to check off "Use UUID for cftoken". This is already checked but it is still reported as an issue. Has anyone run into this? Does anyone know how to resolve this in the CFADMIN or in CF code?

Comment: [Read this blog post from Charlie Arehart](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/7/10/uuid_for_cftoken_does_not_block_simple_cftokens)

Comment: I am going to use J2EE sessions for this site. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What your scanner was complaining would most likely be CFID, not CFTOKEN.

See: [How do I secure CFID for PCI compliance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943261/how-do-i-secure-cfid-for-pci-compliance)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to set session management to use jsessionid.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html

As an added bonus, you can serialize session data when you use jsessionid. That may or may not matter to you, but your basic problem should be solved by switching to J2EE sessions in the ColdFusion Administrator.

You might also want to consider moving to ColdFusion 10 or Railo to take advantage of HTTPOnly cookies, which are not readable using Javascript, using the secure flag on cookies, and using SessionRotate() after login to prevent session fixation.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/security-improvements.html

Pete Freitag's blog reminded me that CF 9.01 and later have a flag that can be set to use HTTPOnly session cookies using java args, or you can use setClientCookies = false. As @Henry pointed out, you will need to do one of those things to get rid of CFID and CFToken creation:

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/764.cfm

Comment: may not work, see comment at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943396/35634

Comment: In Application.cfc settings, use setClientCookies = 'no' to prevent CFID and CFToken from being set.